# What is the line-continuation character in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

How to write a string manipulation in multiple lines like this in VBA? ( " _" is not working here)

```
szStr= szStr & "1=" & szVar1 & ";50=" & szVar50 & _
                    ";79=" & szVar71 & ";7971=" & szVar7971 & _
                    ";7423=" & szVar7423 & ";9523=" szVar9523 & _
                    ";1138=" & szVar1138 & ";109=" & szVar109 & _
                    ";9526=" & szVar9526 & ";"
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that's it. What is your error message?

Comment: @parakmiakos I'm getting this error `Compile Error: Expected: end of statement`

Comment: if this is your code, you are missing an ampersand (`&`) on the 3rd line `";9523=" szVar9523`

Answer (score 3):

Using `_` is correct, but you are missing an `&` between `";9523=" szVar9523`. It should read:

```
szStr= szStr & "1=" & szVar1 & ";50=" & szVar50 & _
                    ";79=" & szVar71 & ";7971=" & szVar7971 & _
                    ";7423=" & szVar7423 & ";9523=" & szVar9523 & _
                    ";1138=" & szVar1138 & ";109=" & szVar109 & _
                    ";9526=" & szVar9526 & ";"
```